# Kubectl JSONPath expression to obtain cluster.server property based on current-context

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I'd like to use kubectl with only jsonpath to obtain the current cluster address. I've tried the following, and many permutations of it, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.clusters[?($.current-context)].cluster.server}'
```

Is this possible using only jsonpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--minify` flag:

> --minify=false: Remove all information not used by current-context from the output

And then filter the `server` field from the current context output:

```
kubectl config view --minify -o jsonpath='{.clusters[].cluster.server}'
```